# Seo procedure for url mapping

Tags: seo, https, sitemap

I am moving my site from http to https.
Currently google has indexed about 800 urls out of 157000 urls which is provided in my sitemap xml.(sitemap links of a particular page : domain.com/username) 
Do i have to create a url mapping as stated in webmaster help.
If yes then what is the process of url mapping is details and how do i submit it via search console without affecting the old indexed urls?

Comment: If your site can properly be crawled, then the sitemap is largely ignored except to audit the ability to properly crawl the site. You do not need a sitemap unless your site is extremely large and cannot link all pages or you have content behind a login or paywall. If this is the case, then you need to either allow Google access to those pages or remove them your sitemap. Cheers!!

Comment: Moving from HTTP to HTTPS, you will need to do one of two things; one, use a canonical tag to point to the HTTPS version of the page, or two, redirect HTTP to HTTPS which is easier and preferred. You will need to update your sitemap to reference HTTP if you decide to use one. As well, make sure all your links are now HTTPS and not HTTP. Your HTTP site will disappear and your HTTPS site will become indexed. You are, in effect, starting over. It will take months depending upon number of pages, freshness, popularity, topic trend, etc. It will all work out fine. You just have to be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the only thing that you are changing is moving to https, then all that you would need to do is add the following code to your .htaccess file, and make sure that is is above everything else (if you already have code on the .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Be sure to replace www.example.com with your actual domain name.

Next, be sure that all versions of your website are verified in Google Console. This includes the www version, non-www version, as well as the ssl-www version, and the ssl-non-www version. Be sure to tell Google which version of the 4 is the preferred version.

Comment: The entries in the sitemap have to be updated as well. Cheers!!